# What do I need for buying a good microphone

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, sound, purchase-advice

I'm trying to buy a new microphone for recording vocals, and I though about [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-USB-Condenser-Sound-Recording-Microphone-with-Adjustable-Metal-Scissor-Arm-Stand-Holder-Mic-Wind-Screen/32602812776.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.119.lQdPvb&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_2_10056_10065_10055_10068_10054_10069_10059_10073_10017_10070_10060_10061_10052_10062_10053_10050_10051,searchweb201603_1&btsid=2b50b68b-955d-4a19-a10b-29946513a270) .

I don't know anything about voice recording so I hope if someone helps me to pick a good one which costs lower than 70 $.

I noticed that some are using the term amplifier for the microphone is it required or just the microphone with the Wind Screen Pop Filter would be enough for home recording.

PS : This microphone is not for me its just a birthday gift so I really need to pick something good.

Comment: Yukina - the way you have worded this question leaves it very opinion based (and arguably no microphones under $70 are good...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that microphone is probably reasonably good. It is very low-price compared to the kinds of microphones found in professional studios. However many of those cheap Chinese clones perform remarkably well considering their very low price.

Comment: One small caveat is that it won't be easy to give a recommendation based on the reputation of the manufacturer, so it will be a bit of a gamble (albeit low-stakes).

Comment: Indeed the "manufacturer" may not even be known to the distributor. Those kinds of products lose their identity almost before leaving the factory.  And there is no guarantee that you will even receive what is shown in the photo.

Answer (score 1):

At that price range it really isn't all that important as most will have similar build/sound quality. It's not until you get in the hundreds of dollars when it becomes a choice of sonic qualities. Most people would regard a $70 mic as garbage. The question you should ask is, will it work? And how long for?